# LibGDX -no suitable method found for setRegion(Objec)

Tags: java, android-studio, libgdx

I am following the codeschool tutorial on making mario, and bumped into this problem a few times. I have been unable to resolve it for a week or so.
 The problem is during a set method that comes as part of LIBGDX

```
 setRegion(walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true))
```

more context below.

```
public void update(float dt){
   stateTime += dt;
   setPosition(b2body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2, b2body.getPosition().y - getHeight() / 2);
   setRegion(walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true));
```

`walkAnimation` is also defined in an earlier method.

The error from android studio is

> Error:(33, 8) Gradle: error: no suitable method found for
>   setRegion(Object) method TextureRegion.setRegion(Texture) is not
>   applicable (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to Texture)
>   method TextureRegion.setRegion(TextureRegion) is not applicable
>   (argument mismatch; Object cannot be converted to TextureRegion)

Does anyone know why the object can't be converted? Is there another way of writing this?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show the code part where you declare/initialize walkAnimation?

Comment: The Animation class was changed in LibGDX version 1.9.5 to be generic. To make it work with TextureRegions, specify it's type. I.e. Animation<TextureRegion> animation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(//...);

Comment: Ah thanks so much, I think i need to do a little more reading on the LibGDX texture region usage:
MY decleration was as follows:

private Animation walkAnimation;
    
then in a goomba method 
        walkAnimation = new Animation(0.4f, frames);

Comment: @AdamMcMurchie the correct usage of Generics helped to solve the problem, right? If so, could you accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it will be a wrong usage of Generics. You must declare the frame type with an animation.
`getKeyFrame()` returns the type you declared your `walkAnimation` with - see [the API documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Animation.html#getKeyFrame-float-boolean-).

From the [LibGDX documentation (excerpt)](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation):

```
// on initialization 
Animation<TextureRegion> walkAnimation = new Animation<TextureRegion>(0.025f, walkFrames);
// in render method
TextureRegion currentFrame = walkAnimation.getKeyFrame(stateTime, true);
```

`setRegion()` accepts amongst others a `TextureRegion` as you can read in [the API](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/TextureRegion.html#setRegion-com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion-)